# Does Azure Devops have to get new clones every single pipeline?

Tags: react-native, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We use on-premise Azure Devops for React Native application lifecycle. Its agent works on Mac as you guessed.

In our pipeline, we start with cloning repo to the folder. Then it continues with installations like node_modules, pods etc. Even after it's over, we start the builds to get ipa and apk. After the completion of the deployments, we delete everything that exists and prepare the agent to start a new job.

But I don't want to clone the whole repo again after PR and do npm and pod install even though I haven't made any changes in package.json. This is the most important problem for me. I want the pipeline to only get the most recently changed places and continue the flow, if the package.json has changed, do npm install, etc.

Because cloning whole repo, running npm install for all PRs is so expensive, like %25 of completion time of each single pipeline.

Is it possible to define a pipeline like this with Azure Devops? Or if you have alternative solutions, I sincerely request you to share them.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you check the documentation for a section on settings that control cloning behavior? It's there.

Comment: I may not have found what I wanted in a documentation consisting of hundreds of pages. Do you have any link, advice, comment or solution? Thanks.

Comment: Really? The **first result** when you Google "*azure pipelines clone behavior*" explains what options are available.